# java regex to remove unwanted double quotes in csv

Tags: java, regex, string, csv

I have a csv file that has the following line. as you can see numbers are NOT enclosed in double quotes.

```
String theLine = "Corp:Industrial","5Nearest",51.93000000,"10:21:29","","","","10:21:29","7/5/2016","PER PHONE CALL WITH SAP, CORRECTING "C","359/317 97 SMRD 96.961 MADV",""
```

I try to read the above line and split using the regEX

```
String[] tokens = theLine.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
```

this doesn't split at every comma like I want it. 
"PER PHONE CALL WITH SAP, CORRECTING "C", is messing it up because it has additional ,(comma) and " (double quote). can some one please help me write a regex that will escape a additional double quote and a comma with in two double quotes.

I basically want :

```
"Corp:Industrial","5Nearest",51.93000000,"10:21:29","","","","10:21:29","7/5/2016","**PER PHONE CALL WITH SAP CORRECTING C**","359/317 97 SMRD 96.961 MADV",""
```

Comment: Use [edit] option and wrap your code examples in `code block` (`{}` icon in editors menu). This way all characters like `*` and ``\`` will be printed.

Comment: Can you modify source which is generating that CSV line? It doesn't do its job properly since you have unbalanced/unescaped quotes.

Comment: It can be easily solved if you are sure these *orphan* quotes are never near a comma, otherwise knowing how each field is supposed to look like may help.

Comment: Get a CSV parser instead of reinventing the wheel with a bad regex.

Answer (score 2):

There are jobs that parsers are much better at than Regular Expressions, and this sort of thing is typically one of them. I'm not saying you can't make it work for you, but ... there are also open-source CSV Parsers you could press into service.

Having said that, your CSV looks suspect to me.

```
"PER PHONE CALL WITH SAP, CORRECTING "C",
```

That value has three quotes in it -- is it meant to represent a string with only a single quote inside? Or should the C be surrounded by quotes as well as the String?

Normally if you're going to include a double quote inside a double quote you need a special syntax for it. For CSV, the most common options would be doubling it, or escaping it with a character like a backslash:

```
"PER PHONE CALL WITH SAP, CORRECTING ""C""",
```

Or:

```
"PER PHONE CALL WITH SAP, CORRECTING \"C\"",
```

None of which will directly change your problem of using Regular Expressions, but once you have well-formed CSV, your odds of parsing it successfully go up.

Comment: Geoffrey, I already tried apache CSVParser and when it reads this specific line it blows up. like you said this is not a well formatted CSV. every now and then we have files getting creating in this format with

Comment: Geoffrey, I already tried apache CSVParser and when it reads this specific line it blows up. Like you said this is not a well formatted CSV. every now and then we have files getting creating in this format. My job is to parse these files. When I did theLine.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))"); I get only 4 tokens instead of getting a token at every ",

Comment: I don't think there's likely to be a really solid solution that handles malformed CSV. You might be able to patch something together that deals with more obvious cases, which might be enough. But if you're possibly getting mismatched unescaped quotes ... I still feel like you should be pushing back on getting a well-formed file. If you really can't do that .... I think I might then move to writing a custom parser than trying to deal with a regular expression, but even that will be pretty hard if you can't be certain when a string ends.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey for your response, I ended up writing a custom parser.